# Mongodb gap between inserts

Tags: mongodb, performance, insert, delay

I'm using mongodb 3.0.4 without replication. Recently I have found that all data is not visible instantly after being inserted. For example, 100 records are inserted, in first 5 seconds I see only 30 records, after 90-120 seconds I can see the rest of them. Have you ever noticed such odd behaviour in mongodb?

Comment: not me for sure. You have got mongodb installed on your system or you are using any remote service?

Comment: In which environment (local, cloud or any server), did you observe this behavior? What is the writeConcern set on your collection?

Comment: writeConcern is equal to 0, mongodb is installed on my server